# Regular Expressions match randomly instead of around quotes in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program in Java, using Regular expressions, and have run into an error. What I am trying to do, is basically make a programming language, and parse it line by line. Where I am going wrong, is when it tries to find any strings. The thing is, is that I have to have it in the order of identifiers, strings, then integers, but I can have the identifiers find strings. Strings are defined by having double quotes around them. Here is where I have a test, and my expression: [here](http://regexr.com/3docv), or here, if you do not want to go to the link:

```
[^"]([^\W][a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^"]
```

I cannot show my Java code, because it is all over the place, with the way I programmed it. It should just be the expression, and that's it.

Comment: If you are making a programming language, you do not want to be using regex to parse it.

Comment: I'm not sure what this regex is supposed to find. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: I suggest you look into tools to support you in making the programming language, for java there is Antlr, it will generate a parser for you so you can focus on the Code generation and semantic analysis. there is also [Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/) which will instead generate a complete compiler(along with Editors support ;)) , I have to say I tried neither of them

Comment: It needs to find anything not enclosed by double quotes, @AndrosRex It is an identifier, like 'class', or 'int' in Java

Comment: in short : don't code parsers on your own, it will be hard, unless this is for teaching proposes hmmm I doubt even teachers teaches tools

Comment: FYI: `\W` is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) as `[^\w]`, so `[^\W]` is actually the same as `\w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you can explain more what exactly you are trying to match. E.g. give some example texts and what your expression currently outputs for them.

At the moment I think you are trying to match Strings, text that is surrounded by `"`. For example `foofoo"text123"barbar` and your desired output is `text123`.

If defining a regular expression in Java, you need to escape special characters like `"`. Here is a Java-usable version for the Regex you have provided:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\"]([^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^\"]");
```

You may then use the `Pattern` object together with  a `Matcher` object to find your text. Here's the [Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for `Pattern`.

Here is a `Pattern` that matches text surrounded by `"`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
```

Comment: I was looking to find a pattern that actually finds everything not enclosed by `"`, although still having the `[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: Oh, that's a bit tricky for a regex beginner. You need to use **negative lookbehind** for that. Here's a snippet: https://regex101.com/r/cE1xJ8/1

Comment: I have seem to run into a slight problem with your new one. When I try a string enclosed in quotes, with a space, or special character, it finds everything between those. If I do "Hello World!" it get something like "orld" for the identifier.

Comment: Yes, that is because of the **\b**. My provided regex matches a word that is not inside **"**. As you can see **World** fits in because it is only surrounded by the right side. Let me think of a solution and then call back.

Comment: **".*"(*SKIP)(*F)|([^"]+)** would do it, but I'm unsure if the Java-Regex is capable of this (Snippet: https://regex101.com/r/iD9qN6/1). If not, I think, then there is no Java-Regex solution for your problem. You may either use another approach or try it with JavaScript. Java has a built in JavaScript Engine **Nashorn** that allows execution of JS inside Java.

Well, easy to implement would be to match everything you like to match and just skip all results that begin and end with ".

Comment: I found an alternative, if you want it for any future reference(I think). It is **`".*"|([^\W])`**